# How can I change the input shape so that there is no error in 3DCNN?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a 3dcnn classification model that takes 10 grayscale images of (320, 864) size as input and outputs one output.
When running the training, the following error pops up:

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 1, 3, 3, 3], expected input[2, 10, 1, 320, 864] to have 1 channels, but got 10 channels instead

The code below is the code that loads the input.
I want to make the input shape [2, 1, 10, 320, 864].
What should I change in the code that loads the input?

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
  video_idx = idx // 260
  frame_idx = idx % 260 + 41
  video_dir = self.video_dirs[video_idx]
  frames = []

  # Get all files in the directory
  all_files = os.listdir(video_dir)

  # Select only .jpg files
  jpg_files = [file for file in all_files if file.endswith('.jpg')]

  # Extract the number from the file name and sort
  numbered_files = sorted(jpg_files, key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[-1]))

  for i in range(frame_idx, frame_idx + 10):
      # Get the file with the corresponding number
      frame_file = numbered_files[i-1]  # -1 because indexing starts from 0
      frame_path = os.path.join(video_dir, frame_file)
      print(f"Loading image from {frame_path}")
      frame = cv2.imread(frame_path)
      if frame is None:
          raise ValueError(f"Could not load image at {frame_path}")
      frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Convert to grayscale
      frame = frame.reshape(1, frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1])  # Add channel dimension
      frame = torch.tensor(frame, dtype=torch.float32)
      print(frame.shape)
      frames.append(frame)

  frames = torch.stack(frames)  # Stack frames along the channel dimension
  label = self.labels[idx]
  return frames, label
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your for-loop you are making data of shape `(1, 320, 864)` that will be stacked into data of shape `(10, 1, 320, 864)` because `torch.stack` concatenates the tensor list along a new leading dimension. Finally, the videos will be batched with a new dimension by the dataloader and so the final batch shape is `(2, 10, 1, 320, 864)` the problem here is that the model expects the 3st axis to be a spatial/temporal axis and the 2nd the channel axis. It is the opposite here. To solve this, you should simply remove the following line in the for-loop:

```py
frame = frame.reshape(1, frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1])
```

And add the channel dimension **after** the `torch.stack`:

```py
frames = frames.reshape(1, frames.shape[0], frames.shape[1], frames.shape[2])
```

Now, the shape of a single data (before batching) is `(1, 10, 320, 864)` as expected.